# Wordpress text editor input validation. Prevent save when certain characters are used on input

Tags: wordpress, validation, themes, editor, sanitization

I'm trying to create a function on my theme's functions.php file that accomplishes that goal.

I want the editor to prevent saving or updating new posts when certain characters are used on the editor. Characters like non-breaking space, certain brackets and aposthrophes and encoded html entities.

I've managed to create a function to sanitize the input after the post was saved to the database, getting rid of all these undesired characters. I did this by writing a function that includes

```
$wpdb->update('wp_posts', ['post_excerpt' =>$sanitized_post_excerpt], ['id' => $post_id]);
```

and then adding the function as a hook to save_post:

```
add_action('save_post', 'sm_sanitize_HTML_entities', 99, 3);
```

Is there a way to prevent the input of the characters being saved (maybe even displaying a message to the user), rather than updating a sanitized version of the data after it's already been saved?

Answer (score 1):

What da butt? `enter code here`

> Blockquo [enter link description here][1]

Olá
[1]: https://%20xpt.

Comment: Yep, I hadn't thought about that, I'll give it a try. Thx!